# `interact` using Text instead of String

Tags: haskell, text, lazy-io

I'd like to rewrite the `interact` function, but using `Text` instead of `String`. Is it possible to use `Data.Text` and/or `Data.Text.Lazy` to accomplish the same behavior as `interact`?

For example, when I run this program using `String`:

```
main = interact (unlines . map f . lines)
  where f "hello" = "wassup"
        f _ = "wat?"
```

it waits for a line of input, and then prints out a line in response, and waits for the next line of input. I'd like to write the same code and have it work for `Text`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.Text.Lazy (Text)
import qualified Data.Text.Lazy as T

textInteract :: (Text -> Text) -> IO ()
textInteract = undefined

main = textInteract (T.unlines . map f . T.lines)
  where f "hello" = "wassup"
        f _ = "wat?"
```

But don't just special case `textInteract` for this use case. I want it to behave the same as `interact` in all situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.0/doc/html/Data-Text-Lazy-IO.html

has an `interact` already for you :)

Seems like so does http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.2.0/doc/html/Data-Text-IO.html

Comment: *doh*. I should have looked more carefully at the docs. :) By replacing `textInteract` with `T.interact` and adding `import qualified Data.Text.Lazy.IO as T`, the latter version of the code does indeed behave just like its `String` counterpart. It remains to be demonstrated that it *always* behaves like its `String` counterpart, but for now I am satisfied.